# generate unique numbers to 2-Dimensional array using linear search

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm, multidimensional-array, linear-search

The program compiles and I can enter a number, but it doesn't generate or it display the array. When I take out the while condition with the linear search in the randomFillUnique function, it generates and displays the array, but not unique numbers. I needed a 2D array with no duplicate numbers.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <random>
#include <ctime>
using namespace std;

int** gen2Array(int n);
void randomFillUnique(int** arr, int n);
bool lSearch(int** arr, int n, int target);
void display(int** arr, int n);

int main()
{
    int number;
    cout << "Enter a number: ";
    cin >> number;
    randomFillUnique(gen2Array(number), number);
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
int** gen2Array(int n)
{
    int** arr2D = new int*[n];
    for (int index = 0; index < n; index++)
        arr2D[index] = new int[n];
    return arr2D;
}
void randomFillUnique(int** arr, int n)
{
    static default_random_engine e;
    uniform_int_distribution<int> u(1, n*n);
    e.seed(static_cast<int>(time(NULL)));

    bool result = false;
    for (int row = 0; row < n; row++)
    {
        for (int col = 0; col < n; col++)
        {
            arr[row][col] = u(e);   //generate random number
            result = lSearch(arr, n, arr[row][col]);
            while (result == true)
            {
                arr[row][col] = u(e);   //generate random number
                result = lSearch(arr, n, arr[row][col]);
            }
        }
    }
    display(arr, n);
    delete[] arr;
}
bool lSearch(int** arr, int n, int target)
{
    bool found = false;
    for (int row = 0; row < n; row++)
        for (int col = 0; col < n; col++)
        {
            if (arr[row][col] == target)
            {
                found = true;
                return found;
            }
        }
    return found;
}
void display(int** arr, int n)
{
    for (int row = 0; row < n; row++)
    {
        for (int col = 0; col < n; col++)
            cout << arr[row][col];
        cout << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: because you set your arr[row,col] to u(e), it always finds that value in the array and your while loop in lsearch loops forever

Comment: Rather than randomly picking a number and rejecting duplicates, consider making a `std::vector` of the set of possibilities and then applying [`std::shuffle`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/random_shuffle) to randomise the `vector`. Then just pick the first N elements from the `vector`

Comment: Off topic: Memory leak. `delete[] arr;` deletes the outer array but not the inner arrays. And now nothing points to the inner arrays so they are exceptionally hard to delete.

Comment: @user4581301 Thank you but for this assignment, I was tasked to fill it random the array with the default void randomFillUnique(int** arr, int n). Thank you for the memory leak advice. I'll fix that right away.

Comment: Got you. Will make answer explaining the technique. Probably annoy your instructor to use it, which depending on the instructor, may be worth it.

Comment: @JeremyKahan Thank you. I'll try to figure out how to do that properly. I thought that  arr[row][col] = u(e) would assign it a new number to it if a duplicate was found in the array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are setting the entry in the array to u(e) before you lsearch, lsearch always returns true and your while loops forever. The below, adapted from your code, should fix that (I am assuming the rest of the code behaves as one would expect). As user4581301 points out, there may be better approaches, but I am going with yours enough to get it working, I hope.

```
void randomFillUnique(int** arr, int n)
{
static default_random_engine e;
uniform_int_distribution<int> u(1, n*n);
e.seed(static_cast<int>(time(NULL)));
int nextEntry;
bool result = false;
for (int row = 0; row < n; row++)
{
    for (int col = 0; col < n; col++)
    {
        result = true;
        while (result == true)
        {
            nextEntry = u(e);   //generate random number
            result = lSearch(arr, n, nextEntry);
            if (result != true)
               {arr[row][col]=nextEntry;}
        }
    }
}
display(arr, n);
delete[] arr;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. It works now. I was gonna try putting a temporary variable but you did it for me. Thank you again

Comment: you bet. by the way, I am pretty sure while (result == true) could just say while (result), and my if (result!=true) could just say if (!(result)) or even if (!result)

Answer (score 0):

An alternative approach would be to create a container of all the unique integers which will go into the array, using [iota](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/iota):

```
std::vector<int> invalues(n*n, 0);
std::iota(invalues.begin(), invalues.end(), 1);
```

Then shuffle that container:

```
std::shuffle(invalues.begin(), invalues.end(),
             std::mt19937{std::random_device{}()});
```

Then feed the values one by one into the matrix.

You could also use a `vector<vector<int>>` instead of built-in arrays:

```
using matrix = std::vector<std::vector<int>>;

// initialising a vector<vector<int>> to be a certain size is a bit clumsy
matrix m(size_y, std::vector<int>(size_x, 0));
```

Then feeding the input values into the matrix:

```
for (auto &row : m) {
  for (auto &elem : row) {
    elem = invalues.back();
    invalues.pop_back();
  }
}
```

Then displaying the matrix:

```
for (const auto &row : m) {
  for (const auto &elem : row) {
    std::cout << elem << " ";
  }
  std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

[Here's a full example in an online compiler.](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/DZgshrR4SJ9027Uo)

Comment: Thank you for this. I appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

OK. Here's the easier way to do this I commented on. If std::vector is disallowed, a simple 1D vector will suffice, but a sane software engineer would think really, really hard before selecting it over a `vector`.

I made a few other changes to fix a couple other bugs.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <random>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm> // std::shuffle and std::iota
#include <ctime>
using namespace std;

int** gen2Array(int n);
void randomFillUnique(int** arr, int n);
bool lSearch(int** arr, int n, int target);
void display(int** arr, int n);
//Added to properly delete the 2dArray
void del2Array(int ** arr, int n);

int main()
{
    int number = 10;
    randomFillUnique(gen2Array(number), number);
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
int** gen2Array(int n)
{
    int** arr2D = new int*[n];
    for (int index = 0; index < n; index++)
        arr2D[index] = new int[n];
    return arr2D;
}

//Added to properly delete the 2dArray
void del2Array(int ** arr,
               int n)
{
    for (int index = 0; index < n; index++)
        delete arr[index];
    delete arr;
}
void randomFillUnique(int** arr, int n)
{
    //do the seeding here
    static default_random_engine e(static_cast<int>(time(NULL)));
// otherwise
//    e.seed(static_cast<int>(time(NULL)));
// runs every time reseeding the RNG to potentially the give the same results
// if run more than once in a second. Plus the seeding is expensive.

    std::vector<int> v(n*n); // make and size vector
    std::iota (v.begin(), v.end(), 0); // init vector with 1 through n*n
    std::shuffle(v.begin(), v.end(), e);

    size_t index = 0;
    for (int row = 0; row < n; row++)
    {
        for (int col = 0; col < n; col++)
        {
            arr[row][col] = v[index++];   //generate random number
        }
    }
    display(arr, n);
    del2Array (arr, n); // frankly I don't think you want his here
                        // why fill an array only to delete it?
                        // more logical to display and delete back in main.
}

void display(int** arr, int n)
{
    for (int row = 0; row < n; row++)
    {
        for (int col = 0; col < n; col++)
            cout << arr[row][col] << "\t"; //added a tab to make the printing easier to read
        cout << endl;
    }
}
```

[Documentation on `std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector)

[Documentation on `std::shuffle`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/random_shuffle)

[Documentation on `std::iota`.](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/iota) Which uses exactly this technique to demonstrate `iota`. Funny, huh?

Comment: Thanks for all help and advice. I'll take note of it.